# WCF Net.Pipe Endpoint

Tags: wcf, net.pipe

On our build server, we have a service that calls another service on the same box via net.pipe, but it is failing saying that there is no endpoint listening to net.pipe. IIS does have Net.pipe set for both the calling and called service.

```
  <endpoint address="net.pipe://build.QQQQQ.com/QQQ/QQQ.svc"
            binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IMembershipService"
            contract="QQQ.IMembershipService" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IMembershipService">
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="host/ABCDF.XX.net" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
```

Note: **build.QQQ.com** is actually **ABCDF.XX.net**. is that the problem, do they need to match even though they are the same.

Comment: This may have been related to not having security credentials that WCF liked. It appears to block users that it thinks are network requests.

Answer (score 0):

IMO - they **should** much.

I'd try to remove last "/QQQ.svc" from address.